# Wheel spacers don't fit

Tags: honda, wheels

I ordered a set of 4 pcs wheel spacers online for my 2017 Honda Rancher 420 4x4.
Got spacers in today,they don't fit my wheels.The wheels don't fit over the rim that is sticking up inside lug nuts.
[image]
Is there any way to make it fit ?
Any advice ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Do not machine that lip off, it is there to locate the wheel correctly.

You need to get the correct adaptor, better yet, get a set of wheels with a different offset that will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Seems they are aluminum wheel spacers.Where did you get these wheel spacers? Why not return for refund directly? I think modifing will cost you much time and effort.

Comment: Bought from Hexautoparts last monday.I live in Canada and contacted this seller yesterday,they told me these wheel spacers fit 2007 Honda Rancher 420 not 2017.My bad,I bought the wrong year,just as Ukko said,I should take correct measurement of center bore size .I like these honda rancher wheel spacers and they are protected well and very strong.If I return to them,the shipping fee is not a small expenditure.So I asked such a stupid question here and wonder anyone whether have experienced before.

Answer (score 2):

The measurement that you need to be looking at is the center bore size of the wheels, the hub, and the spacers.

The first thing I would do is look at the wheels themselves.  If they are aftermarket often they will have a larger bore with the idea that you will need to use hub centric rings to make things fit.  The wheels I use for snow tires are like this and the hub centric rings have stuck to the wheels, if this is your situation you might just be able to take the rings out of the wheels and be good.

If that is not the case you will need to get the correct wheel spacers.  Measure the center bore on both the wheels you want to use and then order the correct ones.  If they are too small at the wheel interface you can always add hub centric rings to even things out.

In all of these cases be aware that all of this is increasing the forces the hub will need to handle while cornering, so just give your suspension a little bit of extra love and attention when doing maintenance.

Comment: I would elaborate a bit on the additional forces the hub encounters when cornering due to spacers.  OP doesn't understand hub bore, so I assume they also do not understand suspension geometry and the like.  That or remove it as it's unrelated to OP's actual question. (no offense meant)

Comment: @iDriveSidewayz no offense taken.  I feel like the fact that the OP did not know about the importance of the center bore on spacers made me feel like they also may not know about the downsides to them.  That may not be 100% included in the text of question, but it is included in the subtext of having asked the question in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If they were ordered legitimately from a reputable company, there shouldn't be any issue in returning them for spacers that fit your hub diameter and center (unless you have aftermarket rims in which case you may need to take measurements and have custom spacers made).

If you're only looking for a way to modify the spacers you now have, I'd question the legitimacy of how you "acquired" them.

Comment: How does this actually answer the question? For example, I have ordered a set of custom spacers from a machinist, and he absolutely wouldn't take them back as he barely makes enough profit on each set and doesn't have large enough volume of orders to keep them stored for reselling later .